# Azure VNet to VNet in different region

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm

I have two VMs in different regions, VM1 (Europe) and VM2 (NA). I was able to figure out how to connect them through a gateway VNet-VNet and through Virtual Network peering. My end goal is to be able to use the internet in VM1 (Europe) as if I was browsing from VM2 (NA) but only for one app (Google Chrome). Also both of these machines are Windows Server 2016.

I'm not sure if VNet-VNet or Virtual Network Peering supports internet transmission. I think that I'm getting somewhere with the Route Table but I'm not that knowledgeable in that, so far I'm not having much success. Is it the right path to the solution to my problem?

The other problem is that I want to use it only for an app. Google Chrome to browse in VM1 through the other VM2 but all the other apps are connected directly through the internet. I read up a solution to use Windows Firewall rules with two different Network Security rules (Private/Public), so I set up two Network Interfaces in my VM. However, as soon as I change one Network rule from Public to Private in PowerShell both of them change. Is there a way to set one Network to Private and another to Public or that will never work since they are on the same Virtual Network? I also can't attach a Network Interface if it is connected to a different Virtual Network (which I think is normal?).

Or maybe I'm completely in the wrong path and you guys can offer some directions, maybe an easier solution?

So in short theses are my troubles. I'm not that knowledgeable in Azure or Network Administration but I'm learning as I go through it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you have a strong understanding of network routing, your goal will be difficult to achieve. Networks know very little about the applications running above them. Routing a single application is very difficult. Instead, route the traffic based upon the destination address. I would launch a VM in the target region and then connect to that machine to run Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The thing is the RDP connection is too slow for me if I connect in another region. I think I have a better idea. I'll have two network interface. One to connect Via RDP (and block all traffic) and the other to route all traffic to browse internet. Any idea how can I achieve to route all internet traffic from a subnet? Through a route table or Load Balancer? I'm having difficulty with both so far.